# What is this circuit symbol?

Tags: symbol

[image: circuit symbol]

Does anyone know what this circuit symbol is? My guess is that it's a surge protector but I'm not sure

Context

[image]

Comment: It would help to show the context this symbol is in.

Comment: Just edited to add context

Comment: @SivaDotRender The context image is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Edraw: Standard Process Flow Diagram Symbols and Their Usage](http://www.edrawsoft.com/pfdsymbols.php), it is the symbol for a pump.

Comment: It turns out that the SPKx5 referenced in the image is a gas valve. So either this is the symbol for the valve itself, or some kind of ancillary pump associated with the valve's application.

Comment: I did some research and yes you are correct. This is the pump that pumps oil into a piston in order to open the valve.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a general pump symbol to me.

[image]

ref:   http://processprinciples.com/2012/07/autocad-pid-pump-symbols/